# Simple image shrink and expand using variables within document.getElementById();

Tags: javascript

I'm using a php while loop to create a table of images and text.
Within  each row at the top right corner is a plus and minus sign.
Only the plus and minus signs have an onclick event. 
for example

Every time a new row is created the id of the image and signs increment by 1.

`Row 1` has `id="img1"` plus sign has `id="1"` minus sign has `id="1"`.

`Row 2` has `id="img2"` plus sign has `id="2"` minus sign has `id="2"` and so on.

Here is my script :

```
function shrink(){
    var id = this.id;
    myimg = document.getElementById('img1');
    myimg.style.width = "200px";
}
function expand(){
    var id = this.id;
    myimg = document.getElementById('img' + id);
    myimg.style.width = "300px";
}
```

Shrink works but I don't have control over which image to shrink with it's corresponding 
plus or minus sign.

The main question is how can I get `myimg = document.getElementById('img' + id);` to work with the corresponding variable id?

Sample Table

```
<table>

<tr>
<td style="vertical-align:top;">

    <a href="http://www.theverge.com/2013/6/13/4426360/massive-battery-life-killer-graphics-can-intels-haswell-deliver-on" target="_blank"><img src="http://cdn0.sbnation.com/entry_photo_images/8439797/DSC_4162_large_large.jpg" 
    width="300px" 
    style="padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;" id="story1"></a></td>
    <td style="vertical-align:top; margin-left:">
    <img src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQEs9xG9jEdXgirA-4GTEHLQ2VRdWjTjj0TChR49NBXdTbnq0H0" name="up" style="position:relative; right:0px; margin-top:20px; float:right;" width="20px" class="1" onclick="shrink()">
    <h4><a href="http://www.theverge.com/2013/6/13/4426360/massive-battery-life-killer-graphics-can-intels-haswell-deliver-on" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:orange;">Massive battery life, killer graphics: can Intel's Haswell deliver on the hype?</a></h4><date>The Verge - 
    12 hrs ago</date><p class="intro">For years now, it seems everyone has been waiting for Haswell, the latest processor from Intel that promises major improvements to graphics performance and battery life. The new silicon just...<br>
    New York City,United States </p></td>
    </tr></table>

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZMkmc/
```

Comment: How are you calling `shrink()` and `expand()`? Assuming `this` actually is the clicked plus or minus element then your `expand()` code should work as is and you just need to change `shrink()` to match it. Note though that you're creating invalid html if you're giving the same `id` to multiple elements.

Comment: You cannot use two same `id` on the same page. Consider nnnnnn 's comment. Can you please show us the table as well?

Comment: I included table in original post and made a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Assigning an id to every image on the page is a bit excessive. Instead, use relative dom navigation. Let's say your table is set up like this (and it shouldn't be because this is horrible html design here :-p):

```
<tr>
    <td><img src="somefile.png"/></td>
    <td>
        <span onclick="grow(this)">+</span>
        <span onclick="shrink(this)">-</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><img src="somefile.png"/></td>
    <td>
        <span onclick="grow(this)">+</span>
        <span onclick="shrink(this)">-</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then your javascript will look like this:

```
function fixDimensions(img) {
    if (img.style.width == '') {
      img.style.width = img.width + 'px';
    }
    if (img.style.height == '') {
      img.style.height = img.height + 'px';
    }
}

function grow(obj) {
    var img = obj.parentNode.parentNode.cells[obj.parentNode.cellIndex - 1].getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    fixDimensions(img);
    img.style.width = parseInt(img.style.width) / 4 * 5 + 'px'; // - 25%
    img.style.height = parseInt(img.style.height) / 4 * 5 + 'px'; // - 25%
}

function shrink(obj) {
    var img = obj.parentNode.parentNode.cells[obj.parentNode.cellIndex - 1].getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    fixDimensions(img);
    img.style.width = parseInt(img.style.width) / 4 * 3 + 'px'; // + 25%
    img.style.height = parseInt(img.style.height) / 4 * 3 + 'px'; // + 25%
}
```

obj.parentNode.parentNode navigates the selector from obj (the span with the + or - in it) to it's parent (the td) and its parent (the tr).

We grab the cells collection of the tr and select the cell that is previous to the spans parent td (the td before that td) by using the index -1 of the cellIndex of the spans parent td.

My example add and removes 25% of the width and height. You can play with that to your liking.

Comment: I fixed your JS Bin too. There's an issue in javascript with images that if the size isn't set explicitly using javascript it's inaccessible using object.style.width or object.style.height. I added code to fix for this. Also, it looks like I have the logic backwards (grow is shrinking and shrink is growing). I fixed that in both the jsbin and my answer. http://jsbin.com/iridad/2/

Comment: Using jquery for the relative Dom manipulation would simplify it considerably '$(this).parent('tr').find('img')' and the same for setting the size